# How to get exact value of ₹ -733.87 from format_currency('-733.87')?

Tags: php, html

I need exact value whatever I pass to the format_currency() in php. I am passing `format_currency('-2,733.87')`, it is giving correct answer as `₹ -2,733.87`. But if I pass `format_currency('-733.87')`, it is giving `₹ 0,733.87`. I need the answer `₹ -733.87`. Please help on this

Comment: please post your full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use number_format here,
php :

```
echo number_format('-2733.87',2);
echo '<br>';
echo number_format('-733.87',2);die;
```

Output :

```
-2,733.87
-733.87
```

[TEST](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/102d3b0a9c11cb10825d0e9f9d0222c8aa35b7ff)
Here you can concatenate your currancy symbol